# Access outer variables from anonymous class

Tags: php, class, anonymous-class

I was trying an alternative way of doing this :

```
public function index()
{
    $faker = Faker\Factory::create('fr_FR');

    $ideas = [];

    for ($i = 1; $i <= rand(10, 50); $i++) {
        $idea = new \stdClass;
        $idea->id = $i;
        $idea->author = $faker->name;
        //...

        $ideas[] = $idea;
    }
}
```

Instead of creating object and assigning attributes in the loop, I would like to create the object from a class, and populate `$ideas[]` with the array_pad() function :

```
public function index()
{
    $faker = Faker\Factory::create('fr_FR');

    $ideas = [];

    $idea = new class {
        private $id;
        private $author;

        function __construct() {
            $this->id = count($ideas) + 1;
            $this->author = $faker->name;
        }
    };

    array_pad($ideas, rand(10, 50), new $idea);
        
}
```

So I need to access `$faker` and `$ideas` from the anonymous class. I tried to pass them to the class like this :

```
$idea = new class($ideas, $faker) {

    private $id;
    private $author;

    private $ideas
    private $faker

    function __construct($ideas, $faker) {
        $this->id = count($ideas) + 1;
        $this->author = $faker->name;
    }
};
```

But I get a

> Too few arguments to function class@anonymous::__construct(), 0 passed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sad news: you cant use `array_pad` for this.

Here the fixes you need to apply to get rid of the error:

```
// array_pad($ideas, rand(10, 50), new $idea);
array_pad($ideas, rand(10, 50), $idea); // remove new
```

Since you did the new already here:

```
$idea = new class($ideas, $faker) {
```

Even though this will fill `$ideas`. It will store the same reference to your `$idea` over and over. Which means if you alter one element this change will be on all elements (i guess this is not desired).

In order to get this working you will have to use a loop, which creates a new `$idea` for every entry:

```
$faker = Faker\Factory::create('fr_FR');

$ideas = [];

for ($i = rand(10, 50); $i > 0; $i--) {
    $ideas[] = new class($ideas, $faker) {
        private $id;
        private $author;

        function __construct($ideas, $faker) {
            $this->id = count($ideas) + 1;
            $this->author = $faker->name;
        }
    };
}
```

Working [example](https://3v4l.org/sAguM).

## Additional information

Instead of doing this

`for ($i = 1; $i <= rand(10, 50); $i++)`

better do this

`for ($i = rand(10, 50); $i > 0; $i--)`

The reason is the comparison is getting called on every loop, so you generating a new random number on every loop. [Example](https://3v4l.org/d1AIP)

This is problematic because you tend to get way more low numbers like this. For example to get 50 loops the random has to return `> $i` every time - which is very unlikely.

One more thing: [array_pad](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-pad.php) returns the filled array, so you'd have to write

`$ideas = array_pad(...`

Comment: Concise! Is there any performance difference between array_pad and the for loop ?

Comment: Well you cant compare them unless they yield the same result. Generally speaking it is good practice to use the array functions when appropriate, since they are highly optimised.